# Godaddy does not propagate txt record with host _acme-challenge

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am trying to set up a lets encrypt ssl certificate on my doamin xxx.com.hk

It does matter what I try, godaddy does not propagate txt record for host _acme-challenge or _acme-challenge.xxx.com.hk or _acme-challenge.cam

The only one they propagate is the @

Ideas?

Comment: https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Problem-adding-txt-record-for-letsencrypt/td-p/115376 or  https://nz.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/DNS-text-record/td-p/109596

Comment: no, tried both and nothing work! i searched for ours and nothing

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this. I was able to make it work by putting the challenge under both @ and _acme-challenge. Once @ was established it appeared to link over to the other.

I was stuck like you and had a hash on _acme-challenge. Then I tried again on the @ and did "nslookup -q=txt yoursite.com" and waited for it to show up and when it did and I continued certbot pulled up the old hash on _acme-challenge. Once I synced them both to be the same it went through. A note, _acme-challenge was the key and certbot appended the site name after it upon detection, _acme-challenge.yoursite.com. I was doing this under Windows-Ubuntu subsystem with "certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns"

Comment: I don't understand DNS enough to explain why this works, but it does. I'm using Plesk on CentOS7. I didn't need to change the _acme-challenge TXT record at all. I did have to add the @ TXT entry at my ISP (Plesk won't allow an @ TXT record). I'd been fighting this for days, but after adding that @ TXT record everything worked in seconds.